# Using ec2 tag to create a Metric alarm on ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I'm trying to define an alarm for every new instance I bring up using ansible scripts.
It is easy to achieve using:

`- name: Create CPU utilization metric alarm
  ec2_metric_alarm:
    state: present
    name: "cpu-low"
    metric: "CPUUtilization"
    statistic: Average
    comparison: ">="
    threshold: 80.0
    unit: "Percent"
    period: 300
    evaluation_periods: 1
    description: "It will be triggered when CPU utilization is more than 80% for 5 minutes"`

Notice that I'm using **cpu-low** as the alarm name. That is not what I want since I can have more than one instance triggering that alarm. Therefore, I would like to use the ec2 tag `'Name'` which I don't know how to access.

I was trying to use:

`- name: List resource tags
  local_action: ec2_tag resource=XYZ state=list
  tags: [metric-alarms]`

But that requires the resourceID which I also don't have.
Is it possible to get the ec2 tags on ansible scripts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the task I came up with to use the instance Name on the alarm Name:

```yaml
- name: Get instance ec2 facts
  action: ec2_facts
  register: ec2_facts

- name: Get resource tags from ec2 facts
  sudo: false
  local_action: ec2_tag
                resource={{ec2_facts.ansible_facts.ansible_ec2_instance_id}}
                region=us-east-1 state=list
  register: result

- name: Create CPU utilization metric alarm
  sudo: false
  local_action: ec2_metric_alarm
                state=present
                region=us-east-1
                name="{{result.Name}}-cpu-utilization"
                metric="CPUUtilization"
                statistic=Average comparison=">="
                threshold=80.0
                unit="Percent"
                period=300
                evaluation_periods=1
                description="It will be triggered when CPU utilization is more than 80% for 5 minutes"
                dimensions="InstanceId"="{{ec2_facts.ansible_facts.ansible_ec2_instance_id}}"
                alarm_actions=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123412341234:My_SNS_Notification
                ok_actions=arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:123412341234:My_SNS_Notification
```

Comment: You can alternatively get tags by using the EC2 inventory plugin. Tags will then appear as host variables in the form of `ec2_tag_Name` for the "Name" tag. This can be really convenient, but in practice it is frustrating for provisioning plays, because AFAIK you can't reload it in-memory during the Ansible run, like you can with `ec2_facts` and `ec2_tag`. Thus when you create new instances, those hostvars aren't yet available later in the same run. I wish that the EC2 inventory plugin and `ec2_facts` module were more cohesively integrated.

Comment: Went ahead and posted a separate answer since I think it shows a pattern that is often useful in other contexts. For provisioning I think that fetching results with the `ec_tag` module may unfortunately still be the best way to go.

Comment: What does `state=list` do here?

Comment: As the documentation (http://docs.ansible.com/ec2_tag_module.html) says: `Use list to interrogate the tags of an instance.`

Answer (score 1):

Tags are much more convenient with [the EC2 inventory plugin](http://docs.ansible.com/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script) than all the `register` juggling, but it has some caveats as well. Using the plugin, tags are assigned as host variables with an `ec2_tag` namespace. Your alert definitions might look something like this:

```yaml
- name: Set up metric alerts
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local

  tasks:
    - name: Create CPU utilization metric alarm
      ec2_metric_alarm:
      args:
        state: present
        name: '{{ hostvars[item].ec_tag_Name }}'
        metric: CPUUtilization
        statistic: Average
        comparison: ">="
        threshold: 80.0
        unit: Percent
        period: 300
        evaluation_periods: 1
        description: >
          Triggered when CPU utilization is more than
          80% for 5 minutes
      with_items: groups['your_targets']
```

It's even easier when you're executing normal remote plays (not `local_action`), since you usually don't need `hostvars[item]` in a loop, you simply refer to `ec2_tag_Name` for the host currently being configured.

Now the downside: as an inventory plugin, AFAIK there is no way to refresh the data in-memory during a single Ansible run. That means when using Ansible for provisioning, if you launch new EC2 instances with a play, the `ec2_tag_Foo` variables won't be available in subsequent plays, until you run `ansible-playbook` a second time, and possibly do `ec2.py --refresh-cache` to update locally cached data. This is unfortunate. I wish that the inventory plugin and the `ec2_facts` module were more cohesively integrated.